# Errors when trying to use vget (Youtube video downloading API)

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the vget API from axet to download a youtube video with Java, but when I try to use the library with this code:

```
public class testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s10ARdfQUOY";
            String path = "C:/Users/Dylan/music";
            VGet v = new VGet(new URL(url), new File(path));
            v.download();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It just throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.YouTubeParser.getQueryMap(YouTubeParser.java:193)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.YouTubeParser.extractEmbedded(YouTubeParser.java:177)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.YouTubeParser.downloadone(YouTubeParser.java:59)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.YouTubeParser.extract(YouTubeParser.java:319)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.VGetParser.extract(VGetParser.java:15)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.VideoInfo.extract(VideoInfo.java:98)
    at com.github.axet.vget.VGet.download(VGet.java:206)
    at com.github.axet.vget.VGet.download(VGet.java:63)
    at thingerthing.testing.main(testing.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

Here's the library: https://github.com/Litarvan/vget

I'm not sure if I'm installing it correctly. I downloaded two jar files, the wget-1.2.3 and vget-1.0.9 and put them into my eclipse project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing VGet's dependencies. Just downloading `vget-1.0.9` will only get you that library, not what it depends on (such as Apache HTTP, in this case).

Can you use Maven for your project? Adding vget to your `pom.xml` will pull in all of the correct dependencies for vget and all of their dependencies as well. This graph of dependencies may be quite large, so just adding jar after jar to your project may end up taking quite a bit of time.

The dependency you need, if you use maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
   <artifactId>vget</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```